# Why does my async AWS Lambda require a callback in order to recursively call itself?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Setup: Because of the time limit on lambdas, I am using a lambda to process some work, then recursively call itself to continue the work, again and again until it is complete. It's just a chron job that I split up to make sure it won't timeout if the data is too large sometimes.

It looks roughly like this:

```html
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let response;
    let err;
    try {
        const data = await getSomeAsyncDataToUpdate(); // this won't get previously updated data, so each recursion gets the first X data until there's none left
        response = await updateSomeDataAsync(data);
        if (!doneConditionIsMet(response)) {
            callLambda(); // we do NOT await because the top level lambda would eventually timeout
        }
    } catch(e) {
        err = e;
    }
    callback(err, response);
};
```

This is being called from a Cloudwatch Event (chron).

The Problem:
According to the docs, Cloudwatch Events are asynchronous calls and therefore, do not use the callback. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

> For async handlers, you return a response, error, or promise to the runtime instead of using callback.

Here's the rub: if I omit the callback, the recursive lambda call doesn't happen. I can see that the function gets called, but it does not result in another lambda getting triggered and running.

Why?

I am out of ideas. The only thing I could come up with is that the lambda is exiting before the call actually executes, which would be wild because I assume the actual execution is synchronous. Also, if that were the case, I do not see how calling the callback would keep it alive long enough for that to finish.

If it is working by some fluke, is there a correct way to do this?

Notes on things I've already checked/tried:

- the callback does not keep the lambda alive for a long time. It exits immediately as expected
- I tried every version I could think of with removing the callback and returning something
- As noted in the code snippet, I do NOT want to await the recursive call because that would mean the first lambda has to wait for them all to complete, which defeats the entire purpose of this

Comment: can you post the "callLambda()" function code

Comment: "*the lambda is exiting before the call actually executes*" - this seems quite possible actually. While the http request to call the lambda is prepared in the background, your code finishes and kills any ongoing processes. That it works with the `callback` but not without is very weird indeed, though.

Comment: Have you tried setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` on the first line of your func? See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html